# Locking Range in a Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have used `COUNTIFS()` formula in Google Sheet. Whenever I insert a new row in the worksheet the range of the `COUNTIFS` formula gets updated.

For e.g if my formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(Detail!C2:C10,"CR",Detail!D2:D10,"Delivered")
```

and I insert one row the formula will become

```
=COUNTIFS(Detail!C3:C10,"CR",Detail!D3:D10,"Delivered")
```

As such the newly inserted row is outside the range of `COUNTIFS()` formula and I get an undesired result.

I have tried appending **`$`** to the column part of the range to lock but it didn't work i.e. `Detail!C$2:C10`

Could you suggest a way to lock the range `Detail!C2:C10` regardless of how many rows are newly added.

Comment: If you're adding a row, do you want the new range to be C2:C11? Or do you always want to count C2:C10, the first 10 rows excluding the header?

Comment: Thanks for responding.I wanted it to be C2:C10 and your solution worked for that. but could you also suggest what to do to make it  C2:C11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `INDIRECT` to lock it down for good:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Detail!C2:C10"), "CR", INDIRECT("Detail!C2:C10"), "Delivered")
```

Comment: Thank you @player0. The code is working as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted it to change from C2:C10 to C2:C11, you could mix an indirect reference with a normal one:

```
=countifs(indirect("Detail!C2"):Detail!C10,"CR",indirect("Detail!D2"):Detail!D10,"Delivered")
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom Sharpe.Its working as expected